# Add space on output

Tags: java

Need help on adding space on the output

this is my code

`System.out.format("%.2f"+"%.2f"+"%.2f",ms,kph,mph);`

Output: 0.120.420.26

Expected Output: 0.12 0.42 0.26

Comment: The content enclosed in the `""` is what's actually being printed. So if you want to see a whitespace in your output, add a whitespace inside of the `""`. E.g. `"%.2f "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a space:

```
System.out.format("%.2f " + "%.2f " + "%.2f ",ms,kph,mph);
```